# JAVAFX with Controllers Button

Tags: java, button, javafx, controller

im trying to reach 1 Button From Controller 1 in Controller 2, the Button is not static so im not able to reach him jet :/

```
    public class NeuesSpielController {
    @FXML
    public Button sStarten;
    @FXML
    public Button farbeAuswaehlen;

    public void farbeAuswaehlen() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    Stage test = new Stage();
    AnchorPane test2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Farbwahl.fxml"));
    test.setScene(new Scene(test2));
    test.setMinHeight(200.00);
    test.setMinWidth(400.00);
    test.show();
}
```

here is my second controller

```
public class FarbwahlController {
private MainController main;
@FXML
Button blau;
@FXML
Button rot;
@FXML
Button schwarz;
@FXML
Button weiss;
@FXML
Button gruen;
@FXML
Button gelb;
@FXML
Label bannerFarbe;
static Spielfigur figur;

public void initialize() throws IOException {
    figur = NeuesSpielController.getSpielfigur();
    if (figur != null) {
        if (figur.farbe == null) {
            bannerFarbe.setText(figur.spielernameKomplett() + " " + bannerFarbe.getText());
        }else{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("NeuesSpiel.fxml"));
        NeuesSpielController controller = loader.getController();


        weiss.getScene().getWindow().hide();
```

in this spot i wanna reach the "sStarten" Button from Controller 1 so that i can unlock it

```
    controller.sStarten.setDisable(true);
    }
}

@FXML
public void wahlBlau() throws IOException {

    if (figur.farbe == null) {
        figur.farbe = Farbe.BLAU;
    }
    blau.setDisable(true);
    NeuesSpielController.setSpielfigur(figur);
    initialize();
}

public void wahlGelb() throws IOException {
    if (figur.farbe == null) {
        figur.farbe = Farbe.GELB;
    }
    gelb.setDisable(true);
    NeuesSpielController.setSpielfigur(figur);
    initialize();
}

public void wahlGruen() throws IOException {
    if (figur.farbe == null) {
        figur.farbe = Farbe.GRUEN;
    }
    gruen.setDisable(true);
    NeuesSpielController.setSpielfigur(figur);
    initialize();
}

public void wahlRot() throws IOException {
    if (figur.farbe == null) {
        figur.farbe = Farbe.ROT;
    }
    rot.setDisable(true);
    NeuesSpielController.setSpielfigur(figur);
    initialize();
}

public void wahlSchwarz() throws IOException {
    if (figur.farbe == null) {
        figur.farbe = Farbe.SCHWARZ;
    }
    schwarz.setDisable(true);
    NeuesSpielController.setSpielfigur(figur);
    initialize();
}

public void wahlWeiss() throws IOException {
    if (figur.farbe == null) {
        figur.farbe = Farbe.WEISS;
    }
    weiss.setDisable(true);
    NeuesSpielController.setSpielfigur(figur);
    initialize();
}

public void init(MainController mainController) {
    main = mainController;

}
 }
```

the Idea is i press the "farbeAuswaehlen" button than a new Stage is opening where the players are able to choose a color. when everyone have chosen his color the window disappears and the sStarten button gets unlocked so the program can went on.

Comment: It's very difficult to read code that is written in two different languages

Comment: Im Sorry for this :/ im a beginner this way its easier for me

Comment: You're not even loading the FXML, never mind displaying it. Because you don't load it, the controller will be null, and `controller.sStarten.setDisable(true);` will give a null pointer exception. Even if you do load it, you don't display it, so you will be disabling a button that is not actually visible, which is pretty pointless.